# What does 'throwing up its hands at its own audience' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I'm a non-native English speaker. I'm reading a book about the Simpsons show now. I have a little trouble understanding the last part of the sentence. I read it a million times. I know about the idiom 'throw up one's hands', but I still don't get the proposal. I guess the author says the show gives up trying to please or entertain the viewers, or make them laugh, but I'm not sure about my guess. Am I right? What do you think?

PS: I want to replace this part 'throwing up its hands at its own audience' with simpler wording.

> Starting in Season 8 though, the tone of those jokes changed markedly.
>   Where the show had once been fond of an occasional subtle nudge to let
>   the audience know that it was aware of the absurdities of episodic
>   television (Burns never remembering Homer, Marge reminding Bart that
>   he hasn’t used any of his famous catchphrases in four years), now it
>   seemed exasperated or downright indifferent. For all its great
>   moments, “The Itchy & Scratchy & Poochie Show” is about nothing so
>   much as **the show throwing up its hands at its own audience.**

Comment: As you apparently know, to [*throw up one's hands*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/throw-up-ones-hands) - *If someone throws up their hands, they express their anger, frustration, or disgust when a situation becomes so bad that they can no longer accept it.* Extrapolating from preceding ***it seemed exasperated or downright indifferent*** and ***For all its great moments***, we can assume the writer isn't impressed by the "Itchy & Scratchy" sequences, which rather pointlessly (and lazily, unamusingly?) imply mock outrage at such portrayals of mindless violence.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I want to replace this part 'throwing up its hands at its own audience' with simpler wording.

Comment: I do broadly agree with FumbleFingers and at the same time, I really don't think you could ever say "throwing up its hands at its own audience" with or without *simpler wording*.

Despite your clear explanation, "throwing up its hands at its own audience" won't ever make sense… and therefore, nothing stemming from it could make sense.

Comment: I think @FumbleFingers misunderstands -- "The Itchy & Scratchy & Poochie Show" is the name of the whole episode (as well as the cartoon inside the cartoon).  The mouse/cat/dog cartoon is here noteworthy for its *lack* of violence.  The exasperation is shown by the change to *obvious* pokes at the network (which really did want to add a new character to the show).

Comment: @ami: You're right that I wasn't aware there was an entire episode called *The Itchy & Scratchy & Poochie Show* (so I certainly couldn't know that episode specifically *avoided* the normal violence in the corresponding "cutaway" sequences). But my main point was simply that preceding ***exasperated, downright indifferent*** tells us how the writer here characterises the current attitudes of the show's producers. Which can be contrasted with earlier ***occasional subtle nudges*** (which we can assume he approvingly characterised as witty / artistic breaking of "the fourth wall").

Comment: I think *indifferent* has an odd use here -- as if the fourth wall had been reduced to dust (with digs like an unexplained new family member 'Roy', and the iconic quote "Worst - Episode - Ever").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually watch this particular episode of *The Simpsons*, it's what might be called [*meta-humor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-joke#Jokes_about_jokes_(%22meta-humor%22)) in that it's about how the "show within the show" is losing audience interest.  This is an obvious reference to *The Simpsons* itself, which (after eight seasons) was having trouble keeping its humor actually *funny*.

So the show-within-the-show does typical things like adding in a new, fresh character (angering the fans) or market research (telling them the fans want everything and nothing).  There's also a [now-infamous scene making fun of their hardcore fans.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tfy-DSuc_Kk)

Nevertheless the author of the book seems to feel that this episode went a step too far, and was more *diatribe* than *satire* -- that the show was figuratively "throwing its hands up" as a gesture of *surrender*, because the writers and producers no longer seemed to understand what it was their audience wanted.

In hindsight this seems like pure hyperbole, since the show is now in its *28th* season, with many notable episodes (not to mention a feature-length movie) in-between.  While the writing may not be as fresh as it used to be, the show would have been cancelled long ago if it didn't retain some measure of audience appeal.